# AD FS refresh token before IdpInitiatedLogin SSO

Tags: c#, asp.net, adfs, adfs4.0

I'm using the WS Federation Option in AD FS for users to login to our website (`WebsiteA`). Now we need to do an SSO to another vendor... lets say `WebsiteB`.

To do SSO I just initiate `IdpInitiatedLogin` through my AD FS and the user gets logged in to WebsiteB.

The user generally has 2 accounts in WebsiteB per account in WebsiteA. To login to an account in WebsiteB we set a property in LDS from WebsiteA before IdpInitiatedLogin. This sets a claim for WebsiteB, so it knows which account to use.

The problem is when we set different values in the same property in LDS it will not get refreshed in the claim information for SAML, as seen by websiteB.

Is there any way to refresh the SAML/Token or claims information before IdpInitiatedLogin process so that the user gets logged in to the correct account?

Comment: I don't have a lot of practice in area, so I'm just throwing out ideas that may not be very good, and hence this is just a comment... but I believe SAML tokens are basically cookies. If you can clear the cookie, that will effectively refresh the token. But mostly, I think what you want to do is not well supported by SAML. I see this know, where I manage a Google Apps domain for a small college, and it's a pain to allow one staff member to be logged into two Google SSO accounts at the same time. I generally ask people who need to do this to use two different browsers.

Comment: Thanks Joel, Infact when I see in Cookies there is no any Cookies present which belongs to SAML. However I get your point but even refresh do not work. Totally lost in this particular area!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks Joel Coehoorn, nzpcmad** for looking into the issue I was facing.
After doing a lot of googling for the understanding of the topic, I have not found much references pointing towards it.

As per my understanding, the problem is with the caching of Properties as once you gets logged in.

To resolve the issue I have used **Custom Attributes Store** (using SQL Database).
It queries over database each time when you initiate a **IDPInitiatedSignIn**. Or say each time it sends that claim (Using Custom Claim).

For other devs like me, who may be facing the same problem I am posting my solution here. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Claims are not dynamic.

You have to logout / login to refresh them.

You can do this programmatically - refer https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1439.ad-fs-how-to-invoke-a-ws-federation-sign-out.aspx

**Update**

You will have to login manually.

If your AD attributes are changing so often, claims are not the best solution. You should get the attributes from AD via the C# DirectoryServices etc.

Comment: Thanks nzpcmad,
The article gave me good knowledge about sign out process. 
But it did not mentioned how can we logout and login that user programmatically?

Comment: You have to hit that URL.

Comment: Ok I did that and it just logged me out. How can I login the same usee back without asking credentials..

Comment: I can not use directory services on website B as its a third party vendor.